# Cascade drop down list in excel(dynamically)

Tags: excel, excel-2010, validation

I have two set of excel values which I am generating dynamically named "category" and "value list". I am assigning those values for two named ranges and use them in a drop down list.(data validation list).

"value list" is depends on the selection of category. I want to create a casacde drop down based on those dynamic values . I found several posts but there are static lists.

Here is one post I found [cascade drop downs](http://mauriceausum.wordpress.com/2011/07/12/cascading-combo-boxes-in-excel/)
Can anybody suggests a good way to do this

Thanks

Comment: Is there an issue with the method shown in the site you linked?

Comment: we have define named ranges there.its static

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you have exactly, because 'dynamic' can mean different things for different people, but can you just use the name of the named range?

Comment: By dynamic, are you saying that the items in the Category list can change? If so, you're going to have a hard time accomplishing this. Somewhere, there has to be a reference for the second drop down box. The first drop down box needs to be static, but all subsequent ones can be dynamic. If you're integrating with a database that will retrieve different categories at different times, you may be able to  work this out with VBA, but I still think you'll need to have a reference sheet with all possible categories so that your "child" drop-downs will have a reference.